# MySQL: mass update unique records

Tags: mysql

Say I have a `.yml` file with some data in that looks like this:

```
- id: 1
  cool_data: 124
- id: 2
  cool_data: 178
- id: 3
  cool_data: 101
...
```

Considering all the `id` values represent existing records in the database, how do I mass import the information (possibly over a couple of statements), rather issue an `UPDATE` query for each data point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax in combination with `VALUES()` function:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (id, cool_data)
VALUES
  (1, 124),
  (2, 178),
  (3, 101),
  ...
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE cool_data = VALUES(cool_data)
```

Of course this will actually INSERT if that primary key value does not exist.

Comment: Didn't know this function existed. Thanks a ton!